# Is there a Rust SDK equivalent of the web3.js MessageV0 getAccountKeys method?

Tags: web3.js, rust

I see an [AccountKeys](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/program/src/message/account_keys.rs#L13) struct that is instantiated using a messages static and dynamic keys but don't see any examples of creating one lookup tables on the client side. Do I need to implement the code to populate the `LoadedAddresses` myself?

This is the corresponding method in the web3.js library:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/master/packages/library-legacy/src/message/v0.ts#L78

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `account_keys` directly on the `solana_program::message::v0::Message` struct https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/message/v0/struct.Message.html

And if you want code to help with creating a versioned message, there's a great example at `try_compile` https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/message/v0/struct.Message.html#method.try_compile, which I'm pasting here:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use solana_rpc_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;
use solana_program::address_lookup_table::{self, state::{AddressLookupTable, LookupTableMeta}};
use solana_sdk::{
     address_lookup_table_account::AddressLookupTableAccount,
     instruction::{AccountMeta, Instruction},
     message::{VersionedMessage, v0},
     pubkey::Pubkey,
     signature::{Keypair, Signer},
     transaction::VersionedTransaction,
};

fn create_tx_with_address_table_lookup(
    client: &RpcClient,
    instruction: Instruction,
    address_lookup_table_key: Pubkey,
    payer: &Keypair,
) -> Result<VersionedTransaction> {
    let raw_account = client.get_account(&address_lookup_table_key)?;
    let address_lookup_table = AddressLookupTable::deserialize(&raw_account.data)?;
    let address_lookup_table_account = AddressLookupTableAccount {
        key: address_lookup_table_key,
        addresses: address_lookup_table.addresses.to_vec(),
    };

    let blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash()?;
    let tx = VersionedTransaction::try_new(
        VersionedMessage::V0(v0::Message::try_compile(
            &payer.pubkey(),
            &[instruction],
            &[address_lookup_table_account],
            blockhash,
        )?),
        &[payer],
    )?;

    Ok(tx)
}
```